# Horizontal Listview in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

As the title stated above, I want to create horizontal `ListView` in xamarin.forms.

But the solutions and the examples that I found are not the kind of horizontal list that I want.

Every articles that i stumbled upon, the items are arranged like this

```
item1____item2____item3____item4____item5
```

What I want to do is something like this

```
item1___item2
item3___item4
item5___and so on
```

in windows phone we can do it like this

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanel> 
   <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <toolkit:WrapPanel ItemWidth="222" ItemHeight="100"/>
   </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

Right now, is it possible to create something like this in xamarin.forms?

Comment: What's the use case of this? If you have a listview, usually the list items does have no relation between them. If that's not the case then you should create a list of `[[item1, item2], [item3, item4]]` and use a `StackPanel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no such thing implemented directly in Xamarin Forms. But there is a `FlowListView` control from Daniel Luberda. Maybe this is what you want:

[image]

https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/FlowListView/

Comment: this is exactly what i want! thanks man! now I just need to know how to implement it. thanks once again man

Comment: There should be enough information on the Github page. If you have a specific problem ask a question here. And it would be great if you could accept my answer.